# How to Pass Data from child widgets to parents widgets in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning dart/flutter and I've one demo e-commerce project. I loaded product image, title and price data in child widget using POST API that I need to send to parent widget. Any help?
as below I share the dart file with code and want to show click item in cart without going on or navigate.
Here is home page.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ecom_demo/Screens/Details.dart';
import 'package:ecom_demo/Screens/MyCart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ecom_demo/Models/CartModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {      

  final cartr = CartResponse();
   

 

  Future<CartResponse> getData() async {
    final response = await http.post(
        'http://205.134.254.135/~mobile/MtProject/api/v1/product_list',
        headers: {
          'token':
              'eyJhdWQiOiI1IiwianRpIjoiMDg4MmFiYjlmNGU1MjIyY2MyNjc4Y2FiYTQwOGY2MjU4Yzk5YTllN2ZkYzI0NWQ4NDMxMTQ4ZWMz',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({"page": 1, "perPage": 5}));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return CartResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('error');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Stack(children: [
            Text(''),
          ]),
          InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyCart()));
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
        ],
        title: Text('HomePage'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<CartResponse>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Details(
                                        value: snapshot.data.data[index],
                                      )));
                        },
                        child: Image.network(
                          snapshot.data.data[index].featuredImage,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      )),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Text(
                              'Price:',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                                snapshot.data.data[index].price.toString()),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Text(
                              'Title:',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            title: Text(snapshot.data.data[index].title),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              OutlineButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                 
                                },
                                child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                              ),
                              OutlineButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                               
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


here is my cart...            

    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCart extends StatelessWidget {

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyCart'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                height: 150,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Text(''),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              Text('price:'),
                              Text('price'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              Text('Quantity:'),
                              Text(""),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(25), topLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
            color: Colors.grey),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(''),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

cart model classs...

    
import 'dart:convert';

CartResponse cartResponseFromJson(String str) =>
    CartResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String cartResponseToJson(CartResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CartResponse {
  CartResponse({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.totalRecord,
    this.perPage,
    this.totalPage,
    this.data,
  });

  int status;
  String message;
  int totalRecord;
  int perPage;
  int totalPage;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory CartResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartResponse(
    status: json["status"],
    message: json["message"],
    totalRecord: json["totalRecord"],
    perPage: json["perPage"],
    totalPage: json["totalPage"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "message": message,
    "totalRecord": totalRecord,
    "perPage": perPage,
    "totalPage": totalPage,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.slug,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.price,
    this.featuredImage,
    this.status,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  int id;
  String slug;
  String title;
  String description;
  int price;
  String featuredImage;
  String status;
  DateTime createdAt;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["id"],
    slug: json["slug"],
    title: json["title"],
    description: json["description"],
    price: json["price"],
    featuredImage: json["featured_image"],
    status: json["status"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "slug": slug,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "price": price,
    "featured_image": featuredImage,
    "status": status,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
  };
}


main.dart



        import 'package:ecom_demo/Screens/HomePage.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {



    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at the following, to improve your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: share some of your code so we can help

Comment: hey @pedropimont . i want to send data from productpage to in cart app with proper details.

Comment: share, what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question properly but if you want to pass any type of value from a child to parent then you can do the following :

Say you have to widgets Page1 [parent] and Page2 [child] and you want to pass the string "hello world" from Page2 to Page1.

**1) In Page2 widget :**

When you are exiting Page2 using Navigator.pop, you can pass the value by passing it as a parameter as follows:

```
Navgiator.pop(context,"hello world");
```

**2) In Page1 widget :**

As you might be aware when you push Page2 in the stack using Navigator.push, this is an asynchronous method which waits till the Page2 is popped out.
So go to the place where you used Navigator.push() and add a .then method. So final product will be something like this:

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Details(value: snapshot.data.data[index],)
     )
).then(result){
   print("Result received from Page2 : $result");
};
```

This print statement will print our resultant string "hello world".

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with a state management solution, like InheritedWidget or Provider or Riverpod.  See Google's take on that at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options.

Comment: The BLoC pattern is pretty good for large complex projects.  Below that, it seems to involve a lot of boilerplate that isn't needed by other mechanisms.  Google was recommending BLoC fairly heavily at one point because their AdSense and AdWords mobile apps were using it, but started blessing Provider as a better strategy for most smaller projects.  I suggest that Riverpod exceeds Provider in both minimal boilerplate and flexibility of use.